# multiselect div using left click and hotkeys in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

before i reinvent the wheel, i wanted to know if anyone already has written a js/jquery library that allows user to select multiple div elements by left clicking and holding the hot keys (just like in windows)

Currently i have only this much

http://jsfiddle.net/abarik/nv9hnusu/3/

```
<html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo by abarik</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script><style type="text/css"></style>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <style type="text/css">
    .selected {
    background-color:green;
}
  </style>



<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
 $('.selectable').click(function (e) {
     // $('.console').append('shiftKey'+e.shiftKey)
     $('.console').append('ctrlKey'+e.ctrlKey)
     if (e.ctrlKey) {
         $(this).toggleClass('selected');
     }

 });
 var ids = new Array();
 $('#btn').click(function () {
     var selected_activities = $('.selected');
     var ids = new Array();
     selected_activities.each(function () {
         var id_str = $(this).attr("id");
         var id_arr = id_str.split("_");
         var selval = id_arr[1];
         if (selval != 'undefined' && selval != '' && selval != null) {
             ids.push(selval);
         }
     });
     alert(ids);
 });
});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <div class="left_column">
    <div class="selectable selected" id="participant_1">----1----</div>
    <div class="selectable" id="participant_3">----2----</div>
    <div class="selectable selected" id="participant_5">----3----</div>
</div>
<div class="right_column">
    <div class="selectable" id="participant_2">----4----</div>
    <div class="selectable" id="participant_4">----5----</div>
    <div class="selectable" id="participant_6">----6----</div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Get selected ids">
<div class="console">ctrlKeyfalsectrlKeyfalsectrlKeytruectrlKeytrue</div>






</body></html>
```

Comment: `selval != 'undefined'` should be either `typeof selval != 'undefined'` or `selval != undefined`

Comment: updated: http://jsfiddle.net/abarik/nv9hnusu/4/

Comment: Also I am not sure what you mean by *hotkeys*. Can you please explain that further?

Comment: i think i am able to do specific div select using left/right CTRL + left mouse. Not sure if i can make is specific to LEFT CTRL click only, but thats ok. I am not sure how i can do multi-select using SHIFT button???

Comment: found an answer: http://evulse.github.io/finderSelect/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found an library that does exactly what i need to http://evulse.github.io/finderSelect/